# Confused how the golang project-layout repo works in practice

Tags: go

This question is in reference to the popular [project-layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout).
Is this simply a way to lay out the code, but the actual compilation of a binary will be in the

```
/cmd/app1/
/cmd/app2/
```

So if I have a website, it would still be considered a cmd application that would simply start the http listener etc.

Or are there several "entry" points throughout the layout and not just in the cmd folders?

How exactly would you actual build and run your application using this layout?  (or one of them since from what I understand it supports multiple)

is it like:

`go build cmd/app1/*.go` ?

Comment: The title mentions Github, but the structure of Go code is unrelated to Github (or Git for that matter).

Comment: @ThunderCat sorry, added the link to https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Comment: You don't have to build multiple binaries, that's up to you, but most "apps" only have a single binary, so why would you need a `cmd` folder? The `go build` command operates on packages, so your example of `go build cmd/app1/*.go` isn't valid and leads me to believe you have some other misunderstanding here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: github.com/golang-standards/project-layout  is not popular. It just tries to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just

```
go build ./cmd/app/
```

For example I have this module

```
├── cmd
│   ├── cli
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── web
│       └── main.go
├── go.mod
└── service
    └── service.go
```

go.mod is just

```
module example
```

service.go:

```
package service

import "fmt"

func DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("service processing")
}
```

cmd/web/main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "example/service"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting web program")
    service.DoSomething()
}
```

cmd/cli/main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "example/service"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting cli program")
    service.DoSomething()
}
```

### Build (From root)

Build web:

```
go build ./cmd/web/
```

This will create binary file `web`

run web

```
./web
// output:
// starting web program
// service processing
```

Build cli:

```
go build ./cmd/cli/
```

run web

```
./web
// output:
// starting cli program
// service processing
```

Comment: where would I store or run go deps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build all of your apps inside a folder you can do like this :

```
go install ./...
```

this will build all your apps in bin folder inside GOPATH then you can run whatever app you like.
But if you want to build and run a specific app you can go to that folder and simply run.

```
go build
```

As long as there is a main package in that folder you can build your program.